# Mouse positions is unidentified

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I double click on a `td` it should change the value of input to the coordinates of the mouse.
But this doesn't work and it just shows `unidentified`. How can I fix this script, here it is:

```
function mouseCords(e) {
    alert(e.offsetX + " " + e.offsetY);
    var iksas;
    var ygrik;
    iksas = e.offsetX;
    ygrik = e.offsetY;
    document.getElementById('mouseX').value = iksas;
    document.getElementById('mouseY').value = ygrik;
    var wtff = document.getElementById('mouseX').value;
}
```

Ang here is where I call it:

```
<td id="start_'.$currentTasken.'" nowrap="nowrap" align="center" ondblclick="editCellValue(this); mouseCords(this);" style="'.$style.'" title="'.$AppUI->_('Double click to edit date').'">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
mouseCords(this)
```

To

```
mouseCords(event)
```

---

I also suggest refactoring all your method calls out of the html and into a script tag/file, and adding the events via [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)